# How to split into multiple layers when you've accidentally drawn two layers worth of material onto one layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I drew two separate objects in Photoshop that are meant to be on different layers, but I drew them on the same layer.  They do not overlap right now, but I can't seem to figure out how to separate them.  How can I do that?

Thanks!

*edit* I've added an image to show what I mean.  I have two grids I've constructed and both are on the same layer.  I meant for them to be on separate layers.

The image is here:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0j3e.png]

Comment: What if they are overlapping? Do I just give up and restart?

Comment: @user146405 I've converted your answer to a comment, once you have more points you'll be able to comment everywhere. If you drew two overlapping objects on the same layer, you'll have to redo. However, we may be able to come up with more efficient ways depending on your image. [Feel free to ask a new question!](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do here is:

- First duplicate the layer by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- Then use the mark tool (<kbd>M</kbd>) and mark the object you don't want on your first layer and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Go to your second layer and repeat, just with the other object.

Now you should have two layers with a single object on them both.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help as I learn this :)

Comment: I feel like this answer is actually the better one: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11416/how-to-split-into-multiple-layers-when-youve-accidentally-drawn-two-layers-wort/11419#11419

It's perfect if you're trying to separate something into multiple layers (for me, it was chopping up a sprite sheet)

Answer (score 9):

There's an even faster method,

- Select what you want on a separate layer with your favorite marquee or lasso tool
- Right-click it and select "Layer Via Cut"